Service Bus Console 12c - jar import issue

Java jar file when trying to import from service bus console 12c console, getting attached issue in UI and build error. Not able to trace out other details. where do I need to check for such issue?
Reviewed jar content:

Package path of class file.
Post decompile and compile getting same package path.
Updated existing jar


